# VBScript: Function parameter list too long?

Tags: vbscript, line

in VBScript, I've got a function like:

```
Function InsertPerson(FirstName, LastName, Street1, Street2, City, State, Zip, x, y, z, a, b, c, d, e)
```

When I try to compile this function, I get an "Identifier Expected" error. However, if I shorten the list of parameters, it works fine.

Is there such a thing as TOO long a list of parameters?

I thought vbscript doesnt care how long a line goes..

Is there a way to break my parameters list into 2 lines?

I tried using an underscore, but to no avail.

Comment: I've just tried running this using cscript.exe, and got no errors. What is the context of this (what VBScript version you're using, what other code is there, etc)?

Comment: Also, are you sure that the error is on the line with function declaration, and not, say, on some other line within the function body?

Comment: the actual statement had over 40 parameters, and that's why I thought it wasn't working, because I had no line-wraps in it. Instead, it was the keyword issue. thanks for the Visual Studio tip, I'll open my .vbs files there from now on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok... It turns out that the length of the parameter list was not the issue. the Issue was that one of my parameters was called "Type" and I guess that's a reserved word in VBScript. Of course, textpad doesn't indicate to me at all...

Thanks anyways!

Comment: Visual Studio supports syntax highlighting for VBScript (.vbs) files if you just open them in the editor, and will correctly highlight `Type` as a keyword.